# Typescript ag-grid onGridReady params throws an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid with typescript and React

OnGridReady event params throws an error

```
import { AgGridEvent, ICellRendererParams, ModuleRegistry } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
  const onGridReady = (params: AgGridEvent): void => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  };
```

When I build it throws an error

```
Type error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<AgGridReactProps>): AgGridReact', gave the following error.
    Type '(params: AgGridEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: GridReadyEvent) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'params' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'GridReadyEvent' is not assignable to type 'AgGridEvent'.
          Types of property 'api' are incompatible.
            Type 'import("/Users/subha/admin/admin_demo/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridApi").GridApi' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/subha/admin/admin_demo/node_modules/@ag-grid-community/core/dist/cjs/gridApi").GridApi'.
              Types have separate declarations of a private property 'immutableService'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: AgGridReactProps, context?: any): AgGridReact', gave the following error.
    Type '(params: AgGridEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: GridReadyEvent) => void'.
  104 |           suppressCellSelection={true}
  105 |           frameworkComponents={{ editRenderer }}
> 106 |           onGridReady={onGridReady}
      |           ^
  107 |         ></AgGridReact>
  108 |       </div>
  109 |     </div>
info  - Creating an optimized production build .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE**
```

Comment: When you try use instead AgGridEvent type GridReadyEvent?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @LiH in the comment above, I am using `GridReadyEvent` and it is working fine. So in your case it would be:

```
import { GridReadyEvent, ICellRendererParams, ModuleRegistry } from "@ag-grid-community/core";
  const onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent): void => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  };
```